# how can I write a vhdl program to write digital data in ddr memory in zynq board

Tags: vhdl

I have connected an ADC to fpga on zynq board. So I am now having digital data in fpga. And I want to store this data in ddr memory on my zynq board, for this I have to write a vhdl program.
Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Can you use a processor or do you need DMA? The latter is  not trivial. How much VHDL, Xilinx and Vivado experience have you got?

Comment: I am new in vhdl and I dont want to use DMA.

Comment: You have to use either the processor or DMA. There are no other possibilities.

Comment: So how can I write a program using processor? As I dont have to use DMA.

Comment: I think that good place to start experiments with Zynq is here: https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx2015_1/ug1165-zynq-embedded-design-tutorial.pdf It is tutorial with simplest things you can do with Zynq. Look at chapter 5.

Comment: I just wanted to know how should I start my program. What are different points that I have to include in my program? Do I need to use call function?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your DDR is attached to the ARM PS, the simplest way to get that data into DDR is to route the digital data into a register that can be accessed by the AXI bus. That is the typical way to move data between the FPGA fabric and the ARM processor. It will then be the responsibility of the ARM processor to performs AXI bus reads to that register and store the results in DDR. If your sample rate is slow enough, you could just instantiate an AXI_GPIO block in your Vivado block diagram, and route the digital signal into an "input" port. The CPU would simply poll the AXI_GPIO register periodically and look for a new data sample. This method is simple, but has a lot of issues. For one, the CPU has to waste clock cycles periodically checking the register.

A slight improvement would be to attach the AXI_GPIO interrupt signal to the ARM processor. Your VHDL code would then trigger an interrupt whenever there is a new data sample. That way the CPU doesn't have to continually poll.

The next improvement would be creating your own custom AXI bus module. It could have a Fabric FIFO to buffer up multiple samples, having a status flag register so the host CPU knows what's going on, and also have an interrupt. There are tons of templates and examples for creating your own AXI bus modules.

If you have a relatively high data rate, the next improvement would be to add AXI DMA blocks to the mix. That way, the CPU doesn't have to perform an AXI bus read for each and every data sample, but could periodically setup a hardware block transfer from the AXI bus to the DDR. The CPU still has to get involved some of the time to setup the DMA descriptors, but it's a lot better for throughput and CPU utilization. It's tricky to get this to work correctly while the CPU is running on Linux.

Finally, you could design a module to access the ARM processor's AXI bus HP slave port, which could shove data into DDR directly from the FPGA fabric with no CPU involvement. There are all kinds of hurdles to overcome, especially if you are running Linux on your CPU. This is somewhat advanced so it will take some time to get it working correctly.

So there are some options, from quick solutions to advanced stuff. I suggest you try to determine what solution will be acceptable for your situation, and go with the simplest method that can accomplish your goals.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Can I use DDR of PL section for this purpose? If yes how?

Comment: Yes. If it's a DDR memory controller attached to some PL pins, you should be able to do everything in VHDL. You'll need to instantiate a DDR memory controller and figure out how to attach your data stream to it.

Answer (score 0):

usually your board is self configure with io and DDR memory, which you can be accessed via DMA using Linux or baremetal. I think it would be an easier approach with less development to manage the DDR. Only HDL code for driving the ADC.